# How to add a unique constraint to a SQL Server SELECTIVE XML INDEX

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Given the following SELECTIVE XML INDEX

```
CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX [PropertyIndex_Property] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Data]
)
FOR
(
[Property] = '/Data/Property' as XQUERY 'xs:string' SINGLETON
)
```

How would I add a uniqueness constraint so that at most one row can have a given value of what is in the path `/Data/Property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a computed column where you extract the value from the XML and then add a unique constraint on that column.

To extract a value you need a function.

```
create function dbo.GetProperty(@X xml)
returns nvarchar(50) with schemabinding
as
begin
  return @X.value('(Data/Property/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)');
end;
```

Adjust the size of the return value to match what you have in the XML. A unique constraint is implemented as a unique index in SQL Server so the max for nvarchar is 450 characters and for varchar it is 900 characters.

Use the function in a computed column.

```
create table dbo.MyTable
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Data xml not null,
  PropertyValue as dbo.GetProperty(Data)
);
```

And add the unique constraint

```
alter table dbo.MyTable add constraint UX_PropertyValue unique(PropertyValue);
```

The technique used is called [property promotion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500236.aspx) and has nothing to do with XML indexes. You can keep the index if you need it for queries or you can remove it. This will work anyway and since it is a parameter that is queried in the function it will not use the XML index to calculate the value for the unique constraint.